# Unable to stop timer through another viewcontroller, Swift

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I developing a timer app for an apple watch.

I have two different Views at the moment. One with the actual timer (**TimerController**) and another with a pause-button (**SwipeController**).

I'm trying to stop/start the timer in the TimerController with the action from the button in the SwipeController.

Problem is that the timer stops, but the timer will not start again after hitting the button the second time.

If I press the button one time, the timer stops. If i press it again two times the timer will start again but will not stop when hitting the button again.

Any ideas of what the problem could be?

**TimeController**

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import UserNotifications

class TimerController: WKInterfaceController {
    @IBOutlet weak var timerOutlet: WKInterfaceTimer! //

    @IBOutlet weak var simple_timer_label: WKInterfaceLabel!
    var myTimer : Timer?
    var duration : TimeInterval = 1 //arbitrary number. 1 seconds

    var isPaused = false //flag to determine if it is paused or not
    var elapsedTime : TimeInterval = 0.0 //time that has passed between
    var number_as_a_timer:Int = 0
    var startTime = NSDate()
    var dim_date = Date()
    var current_minute: Int = 0
    var current_hour: Int = 0
    var curent_second: Int = 0

    var seperate_is_paused_bool: Bool = false

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)
        start_timer()
    }

    func timeString(time:TimeInterval) -> String {
        let hours: Int = Int(time) / 3600
        let minutes: Int = Int(time) / 60 % 60
        let seconds: Int = Int(time) % 60

        let com = NSDateComponents()
        com.minute = minutes
        com.second = seconds
        com.hour = hours
        dim_date = NSCalendar.current.date(from: com as 
        DateComponents)!
        self.timerOutlet.setDate(dim_date)
        self.timerOutlet.start()
        return String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
    }

    func start_timer() {
       myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: duration, target:
       self,selector: #selector(timerDone), userInfo: nil, repeats:
       true)
    }
   @objc private func timerDone(){
        //timer done counting down
        if !isPaused {
            number_as_a_timer += 1
            let output:String = self.timeString(time: 
            TimeInterval(number_as_a_timer))
            self.simple_timer_label.setText(output)
            print(output)
        }
    }
    override func willActivate() {
        super.willActivate()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
        #selector(stop_timer(notification:)), name: .stopTimer, object: 
        nil)
    }

    @objc func stop_timer(notification:NSNotification) {

         // Timer is paused. so unpause it and resume countdown
         if isPaused {

            myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, 
            target:self, selector: #selector(timerDone), userInfo: nil, 
            repeats: true)
            self.isPaused = false

            print("timer paused: resumming1")

        } else {
            isPaused = true
            print("stoping timer")
            //get how much time has passed before they paused it
            let paused = NSDate()
            elapsedTime += paused.timeIntervalSince(startTime as Date)

            //stop watchkit timer on the screen
            timerOutlet.stop()

            //stop the ticking of the internal timer
            myTimer!.invalidate()
        }
    }
}

extension Notification.Name {
    static let stopTimer = Notification.Name("stopTimer")
}
```

**SwipeController**

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import UserNotifications

class SwipeController: WKInterfaceController {

    //@IBOutlet weak var myTimer: WKInterfaceTimer!
    var timer = TimerController()
    var status: Bool = false
    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    }

    @IBAction func PauseButton() {
        if timer.myTimer == nil {
            print("timer is nil or invalidated")
            print("Y: \(timer.isPaused)")
            let userInfo = ["stop": true] as [String: Bool] // you 
            could also transfer data

            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .stopTimer, object: 
            nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        } else {
            print("empty block")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your TimerController alive during running SwipeController? How did you switch between two controller?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you aren't ever actually checking for you isPaused boolean to be true or false in your if statement when checking if your timer is paused.

**if isPaused {**                    <-----------

```
        myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, 
        target:self, selector: #selector(timerDone), userInfo: nil, 
        repeats: true)
        self.isPaused = false

        print("timer paused: resumming1")
```

Comment: Where should he paste this line?